# Check if I triggered a select inside the last row of a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="tabella">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="inp" value="some text 1"></td>
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="1">ON</option>
        <option value="0">OFF</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="inp" value="some text 2"></td>
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="1">ON</option>
        <option value="0">OFF</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="inp" value="some text 3"></td>
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="1">ON</option>
        <option value="0">OFF</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to change an input text:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="i_text">
```

with the value of the input `inp` on the same tr when i set `sel` select to ON. But ONLY if I change the select of THE LAST table row.

So if I select ON in the first tr, nothing change.
If I select ON in the second tr, nothing change.
If I select ON in the third/last tr, `#i_text` must be set as value `some text 3`

How can I check I the select triggered is the one inside LAST row?

My incomplete fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fywuonxa/2/

Comment: Share us you code you've written

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child  There are various ways to select the last "thing", to bind an event listener to

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fywuonxa/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use the [is()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_is.asp) method to check if the [closest()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp) table row is the `last-child` of the `tbody` on change of the select box.

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
      $('input#i_text').val('Last row select changed');
    } else {
      $('input#i_text').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabella">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="inp" value="some text 1"></td>
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="1">ON</option>
        <option value="0">OFF</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="inp" value="some text 2"></td>
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="1">ON</option>
        <option value="0">OFF</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="inp" value="some text 3"></td>
    <td>
      <select class="sel">
        <option value="1">ON</option>
        <option value="0">OFF</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" value="" id="i_text">
```